# Flutter bloc, decline accepting requests management

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, clean-architecture, mobile-development

I'm not sure if this is the write place to post my issue.
I have this flutter app(bloc, dio, clean architecture) with event screen. if i'm the owner of the event i can know the number of the new pending requests to join the event through a red circle with number of the new pending requests. on pressing on the red circle i navigate to another screen where there is 2 tabs one that display the already accepted request and another one display the pending request where i can accept or declining the requests.

what i'm doing:

-> in event screen i'm using new instance of RequestBloc where i get the requests to show the number of the new pending requests.

-> in requests screen(where the 2 tabs exist). i'm using new instance of RequestBloc where each tab has its own RequestBloc instance to get the list of request (accepted, pending ), and the pending request tab do some event where it accepet and decline request.

the issue.:
i feel there is heavy architecture here and all the tab reloading when i'm accepting or declinging request. and when i'm getting back to event screen i need to rcreate the screen to update the new pending requests.
I need help here with this mess.